# What would one need to do to get an amateur satellite into orbit?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rocket-science, propulsion

I've recently become interested in amateur satellite packet radio, and I've seen that the bandwidth and thus the bitrate is extremely low on most amateur satellites, not even factoring in noise. So I wanted to create my own (extremely small) amateur satellite which has an uplink and downlink in the gigahertz frequency range, which should provide the necessary bandwidth and bitrate I and many other amateur satellite packet radio enthusiasts are craving.

So how do we get a satellite in orbit?

What would it cost to piggyback on a space shuttle mission?

Is amateur rocketry a viable option to get a satellite into orbit and what would be the cost of such a project?

Are there any regulatory bodies that I should be aware of that enforce activities in the air and in space?

Comment: The hold reason wants to say that this site is mainly for physics as science. But I think you could ask this on the https://space.stackexchange.com where it would be a good match.

Comment: You reach a burnout velocity of nearly 8 km/sec at an altitude of 100 km or greater for a start.

Comment: @peterh I'll move it. Thank you for your guidance (no pun intended :)).